# PowerMock on EasyMock : How to mock web requests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock, powermock

I have a class inside which I have a private method which executes webRequests

```
class Class1 {
    public List<MyObject> call1() {
        ..
        ..
        String response = makeWebReq(url);
        ..
        ..
    }

    private String makeWebReq(String url) {
        Client localClient = Client.create();
        WebResource localWebResource = localClient.resource(url);
            /*fails in the next line */
        ClientResponse localClientResponse = (ClientResponse) localWebResource
                .accept(new String[] { "application/json" }).get(
                        ClientResponse.class);
        if (localClientResponse.getStatus() != 200) {
            //Handle it
        }
        return (String) localClientResponse.getEntity(String.class);
    }
}
```

In the test case for `call1` I'm trying mock the private method `makeWebReq`. But when i run the testCase, it fails in makeWebReq method, in the line which i have added a comment as `fails in the next line`. The test case method id as follows:

```
public void testCall1() {
    Class1 obj1 = PowerMock.createPartialMock(Class1.class, "makeWebReq");

    try {
            PowerMock.expectPrivate(obj1, "makeWebReq").andReturn("A response String");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    PowerMock.replay(obj1);
    assertNotNull(obj1.call1());
    PowerMock.verify(obj1);
}
```

After calling the above test method for call1, it fails in the said line. What is it that I'm doing wrong here?. Any pointers?

Comment: Better to test your code against a real endpoint that you create during the tests. What's the mocking going to prove here?

Comment: @artbristol I want to mock the 'WebRequest'. I just started experimenting with PowerMock and I'm not sure whether mocking that entire method is the right thing to do. Is it possible to Mock only the line where the actual web request is happening?

Comment: Don't mock anything, is my advice. Use a real endpoint, and send a real HTTP request.

Comment: But isnt that against the norms of unit-testing? In the code that Im handling, for each web request, that module reads/writes into databases as well. So, it damages the integrity of the entire database if i add an entry each time i unit-test.

Comment: Pure unit-testing isn't all it's cracked up to be. See this http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2009/11/04/selective-unit-testing-costs-and-benefits/. I'm not suggesting you test your actual endpoint. You can set up a dummy one, and tell it to return whatever HTTP response you want.